# Justify a UL element in the screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-lists

I really hope someone could help me. I want to justify my categories menu in a Wordpress website.

You can see it here, the colourful menu on the top: http://www.postscriptum.hostingas.in/

The menu in the HTML is called "`section-bar`".

**Here is the CSS code:**

```
.section-bar {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    background: #252525;
}

.section-bar ul li {
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 0;
}
.section-bar ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**I tried to put this but nothing changed:**

```
.section-bar ul {
    text-align:justify;
}
```

How can I make it fit nicely into the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 elements in one row, split your wrapper size to 5 elements (for example 1000/5=200px) and set width li to 200px (in this example).

Comment: Sorry, it does not work, the whole thing seems disordered. And I guess that is because the text doesn't fit into all the ils the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site the first thing that comes to mind is to change the css of the li item so that every item is the same width and that it is big enough to put the biggest title on one line.  So to do that I would change the width to be 356px.

```
.section-bar ul li {
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 0;
    width: 356px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but then the website looks like this: http://s22.postimg.org/o6yb71jkx/image.jpg 

To me, it is not what Im looking for. Anyway, happy that someone answered!